# my double-dimensional field doesnt print its content

Tags: c

I was just experimenting with sinus function in `<math.h>` file and want to draw it in a double-dimensional field. code follows:

```
char field[150][11];

for(int i = 0; i< 150; i++)
{   

   double value_of_sin = sin((i*M_PI)/180);
   value_of_sin *= 10; // to take an after-decimal-point number as 'second dimension' of my field
   int intpart = (int)value_of_sin;

  if(intpart > 0) //still grows
     field[i][intpart] = '%';

  else 
  {   
     intpart *= -1; //the sin function is dropping here so i need positive numbers
     field[i][intpart] = '%';
  }   
}

for(int i =0; i<11; i++)
{   
  for(int j =0; j<150; j++)
     printf("%i",field[j][i]);

  printf("\n");
}
```

the purpose was to draw untill 150 degrees (tried to have 360 - but my window is not as width, so it would end up break up among rows). However when trying to execute, the the printf function, it wont print the '%' character but instead just random numbers (well, not random, there is suspiciously repeating '2' and '3' numbers. Well I tried to - on the top of my code - clear the filed by 2 for-cycles and give the field a ' ' value, but didnt help. I would like to ask how to make the printf function print the '%' character.

PS: still newbie, so it may look like silly question, but will help. thanks!

Comment: Try `"%c"` instead of `"%i"` in the printf.

Comment: Adding to @user3386109 comment see the examples here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Several things about your shown code are unclear.

Comment: @Yunnosch what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("%c", field[i][j]);`
should do the trick.

What is happening is; printf is looking for an integer type, so when it prints your field[i][j], it is printing the decimal value, not the ascii value you are looking for.

Comment: yeah, that really silly mistake, i made it probably by incaution, anyway thanks